# Android - Retrieve all data from a SQLite table row

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I have searched and cannot find an answer to my issue so i hope i am not completely barking up the wrong tree (so to speak).

I am new to android and have started to create an app. My app on one screen creates and adds entries to a SQLite database using public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper and this all appears to work.

I retrieve all the data and populate it into a grid, again this now works.

My issue is I am unable to retrieve one complete line from the grid.

I populate/display the grid with the following code.

I have cut a lot out as the grid is made in stages, header, blank lines etc but the grid does display as I want.

The id’s work as when I touch a line it displays its unique id.

The onClick is right at the end and when I use getText() instead of getID() all it returns is the data in the labelDate. How do I retrieve all the labels as listed below?

package com.pump.diary;

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PumpDiaryReview extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pump_diary_review);

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    boolean doFirstHeadings = true;
    String dateCheck = "";
    Integer count=0;

    List<Readings> readings = db.getAllReadings();
    for (Readings re : readings)
    {
        if (doFirstHeadings == true)
        {
            //First record so setup the headings.
            TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
            tr_head.setId(10);
            tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView label_date = new TextView(this);
            label_date.setText("Date:Time");
            TextView label_CP = new TextView(this);
            label_CP.setText("CP");;
            TextView label_BG = new TextView(this);
            label_BG.setText("BG");
            TextView label_QA = new TextView(this);
            label_QA.setText("QA");
            TextView label_CN = new TextView(this);
            label_CN.setText("CN"); 
            TextView label_KT = new TextView(this);
            label_KT.setText("KT");  

            TextView[] tvHeaderArray = {label_date, label_CP, label_BG, label_QA, label_CN, label_KT};

            for (TextView tvHeader : tvHeaderArray)
            {
                tvHeader.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tr_head.addView(tvHeader);
            }
            tl.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            doFirstHeadings = false;
            count = 0;
        }

        // Create the table row
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setClickable(true);
        tr.setId(100+count);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView labelDATE = new TextView(this);
        TextView labelCP = new TextView(this);
        TextView labelBG = new TextView(this);
        TextView labelQA = new TextView(this);
        TextView labelCN = new TextView(this);
        TextView labelKT = new TextView(this);
        TextView[] tvArray = {labelDATE, labelCP, labelBG, labelQA, labelCN, labelKT};

        if (!dateCheck.equals(re.getDate()) || (dateCheck == null) || dateCheck == "")
        {
            //Add a blank line in.
            TableRow tr_blank = new TableRow(this);
            tr_blank.setId(10);
            tr_blank.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            tr_blank.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView label_date = new TextView(this);
            label_date.setId(20);
            label_date.setText(re.getDate());
            label_date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tr_blank.addView(label_date);

            tl.addView(tr_blank, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

        labelDATE.setText(re.getTime());
        labelCP.setText(re.getCP());
        labelBG.setText(re.getBG());
        labelQA.setText(re.getQA());
        labelCN.setText(re.getCN());
        labelKT.setText(re.getKT());
        for (TextView tv : tvArray)
        {
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setId(200+count);
            tr.setOnClickListener(this);
            tr.addView(tv);
        }
        //add this to the table row
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        dateCheck = re.getDate().toString();
        ++count;
    }
    }
    public void onClick(View v) 
    { 
        if (v instanceof TableRow) 
        { 
            TableRow row = (TableRow) v; 
            TextView child = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0); 
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(child.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
            toast.show();
        } 
    } 
}
```

I can supply all the code for the grid creation if required.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you click a `TextView`, it only displays one index from the array but not the whole array? correct? we need to see how the array makes it into your textviews. Are you only applying one index to each textview? regardless i suggest that you should really rework your setup to using a `GridView` and a `CursorAdapter`. these pre-made components might make things much more straight-foward and perform much better. you don't have to do everything from scratch.

Comment: Hi, I have added in the whole class for you to see. It adds in a grid with date headings and times and readings for that day under neath. When the date changes it creates a new sub heading then lists the reading again.

Comment: If you think that GridView and CursorAdapter is the way to display the data do you have a link to a page that shows how ths can be done please.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is I am unable to retrieve one complete line from the grid.
>
> The onClick is right at the end and when I use getText() instead of
>   getID() all it returns is the data in the labelDate. How do I retrieve
>   all the labels as listed below?

I'm not certain I understand the question, but this will give you toast with all the ID's in a `TableRow`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v instanceof TableRow) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) v;
        String msg = "";
        for (int i=0; i < row.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TextView child = (TextView) row.getChildAt(i);
            msg += String.valueOf(child.getId()) + " ";
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here:

```
            TextView child = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0); <------------------
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(child.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
            toast.show();
```

you are specifically requesting the first child of the row and getting the text from it which of course would only yield one value. to get all the rest, i'd suggest going to your `List<Readings>` and specifying the object that you want by index. then you can just print out everything from the object. As for how you'd get this index...with your current implementation, i think perhaps **tagging** your textViews with the index as they are being made and being populated by your `List` might be the most straight-forward.